# jquery .load() not working in safari

Tags: jquery, safari, modal-dialog

I have a modal window, which loads new content after a link is clicked using the jquery method .load()

It is working in all browsers except for safari. I am stumped.

JS

```
<script language="javascript">
function shipCalc() {
$('.jqmWindow').load("/ash/shop/shipping.php?zip=" + document.form9.zip.value);
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form name="form9" id="form9" method="post">
Zip: <input type="text" size="5" name="zip">
<a href="#" id="submitbtn" onclick= "shipCalc();" >zip</a>
</form>
```

I have even tried to call the function shipCalc() with $(document).ready and it will immediately switch the content of the modal when it is opened in ALL other relevant browsers (FF, Chrome, IE)

Whats going on here? Its gotta be right in front of me!

Comment: why don't you use jquery's selector instead of vanilla js in your document.form9.zip.value?

Comment: @corroded could you expand a bit, I am no expert, just using the limited knowledge I have of each

Comment: you're mixing your jquery with normal javascript. you could just use jquery's selector by doing $('#form9 input[name="zip"]').val() instead of document.form9.zip.value. just a hunch on why the behavior is inconsistent

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function shipCalc() {
    $('.jqmWindow').load("/ash/shop/shipping.php?zip=" + $("form[name='form9'] [name='zip']").val();
  }
</script>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: @corroded @EdgarVillegasAlvarado  
I see where you guys are stating I should keep with the jquery selector instead of JS, I agree that is probably more clean but it unfortunately does not solve my problem. Furthermore, I cant even load just a regular page "/ash/shop/shipping.php" in safari. To expand on what I have here...  ".jqmwindow" is a modal window that shows contents of a shopping cart. I am trying to have a link within that modal that loads shipping options, and I used the .load() method to load new contents into the modal window. It works everywhere but safari!

Comment: you have missing parenthesis in your code after .val()

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple tips:

First, use

```
$('#submitbtn').click(function() {
    shipCalc();
}
```

instead of the onclick attribute in your `a#submitbtn` tag, for a similar reason as to why you should avoid combining regular javascript and jQuery expressions.

Second, you should not be passing data through the URL; instead, pass the data to the requested file using load's `data` parameter (see the `{ }` in the .load() method - `{key : val}` is the same as `?key=val`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function shipCalc(val) {
        $('.jqmWindow').load("/ash/shop/shipping.php", {zip: val});
    }

    var value;
    $('#submitbtn').click(function() {
        value = $('#form9 input[name="zip"]').val();
        shipCalc(value);
    });

});
```

Hope this helps!